# ¿Como puedo visualizar arreglos php desde el navegador?

Tags: php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero saber como puedo ver de esta manera arreglos que muestre con var_dump o print_r en php, ya que no e podido encontrar ninguna extension, espero me puedan ayudar.

```
$data = array('name'=>'Juan','edad'=>'20');

var_dump($data);
```

Con esto ya puedo visualizar lo que es el arreglo sin problemas, lo que quiero es saber alguna forma de que a la hora de imprimirlo en el navegador se vea como en la imagen, imagino que se trata de alguna extrensión, o algo parecido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dado que tu array es unidimensional, podemos omitir el uso de un ciclo para obtener los valores, haciendo lo siguiente

```
<?php

$data = array('name'=>'Juan','edad'=>'20');

echo $data["name"];
echo $data["edad"];
```

Que imprime

> Juan20

**ACLARACIONES**

- Hacemos `echo` a la variable `$data` que almacena el array, como es asociativo le indicamos entre corchetes que imprima donde la clave es `["name"]`
- Hacemos `echo` a la variable `$data` que almacena el array, como es asociativo le indicamos entre corchetes que imprima donde la clave es `["edad"]`

Si por el contrario tienes un array multidimensional, es decir un array que almacena otros arrays como el siguiente

```
<?php

$data = array(
            array('name'=>'Juan','edad'=>'20'),
            array('name'=>'Pedro','edad'=>'30')
              );
```

Entonces debemos ocupar un ciclo para acceder a los elementos de este modo

```
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    echo $value["name"];
    echo "<br />";
    echo $value["edad"];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Obteniendo un resultado como el siguiente

> Juan
>   20
>   Pedro
>   30

Aquí en la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php) puedes consultar mas al respecto

Answer (score 1):

David para verlo **visualmente** como quieres en la imagen solo tenes que agregar esta linea en el archivo php.ini de tu servidor local o web

```
xdebug.mode=develop,debug
```

Mas información: https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#mode

Saludos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: David, Tu respuesta esta bien, pero debes añadir información adicional y más contexto a la misma, ya que aunque cumpla con lo pedido en la pregunta, podrían cerrarla por baja calidad. Saludos.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).